# How to select the Particular check box in Selenium data driven framework, without X-path, Id, link text, name,CSS,class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

[image]

How to select the Particular check box in Selenium data driven framework, without X-path, Id, link text, name,CSS,class.

Comment: `without X-path, Id, link text, name,CSS,class` means what ? and add the HTML code instead of snap

Comment: So just to make the question clearer: You do __not__ want to select the checkbox, but you want to select the text after it?! (Which is the label for the checkbox, eventhough it was not coded as a label)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with an XPath since you need to find the element by contained text.

```
//td[.='D1401000093']//input
```

This finds a `TD` that contains the desired text, then finds the `INPUT` descendant. Once you get that, you can click it, etc.

If it were me, I would wrap this in a function that takes the desired ID (or whatever 'D1401000093' is) and returns or clicks the `INPUT`.